# InvokeMember("click") in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, webbrowser-control, invokemember

A website shows a table based options to choose. `HTML` is

```
<td width="33%" class="cont"><input type="radio" name="gatewayIDV" onclick="setBank(11,0,1)">
<td width="33%" class="cont"><input type="radio" name="gatewayIDV" onclick="setBank(3,0,1)">
```

I want to Invoke click of radio of string "setBank(11,0,1)". How do I? all radio name are same but `onclick()` parameter is different.

in JavaScript someone does this some code are here but how I do this in c#

I try this but never work:

```
if (webBrowser1.DocumentText.IndexOf("setBank(11,0,1)", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > 1)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gatewayIDV").InvokeMember("click");
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$("td.cont").each(function(index) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var gonext = true;
        if($this.html().search(searchStr) != -1) {
            $(document).BookingEngine("setAutomationRunningStatus",
                  !tabData.automationRunning);
            console.log(index+":"+$this.html()+":");
            $this.children("input[name='gatewayIDV']").click();
            gonext = false;
        }
        return gonext;
    });
```

Comment: can you give me url of target for test result?

Comment: website login require. how i contact u and give details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multi radio button input you must loop through them,try this:

```
 private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("url");
        }


        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted_1(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
            {
                if (el.Name == "gatewayIDV")
                {
                    el.InvokeMember("Click");
                }
            }
        }
```

**Edited**

For specific radio button

```
 private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(@"E:\Documents and Settings\Ali\Desktop\ww.html");
    }


    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted_1(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
        {
            if (el.Name == "gatewayIDV" && el.OuterHtml.Contains("setBank(11,0,1)"))
            {
                el.InvokeMember("Click");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: but all radio has same name "getewayIDV" how click will perform of onclick="setBank(11,0,1)"