# Why isnt it clicking on the button on the website even though I have the correct class name?

Tags: c#, html, css, .net

So I'm trying to click on this button on a website which doesnt have a ID, the only relevant thing it has is a class name.
It's located inside this one div but i'm not sure if that matters.

nothing at all happends when I try to execute the code from my button event.
Why is that?

This is what I've tried so far. (I've tried multiple different options but none seem to work)

```
HtmlElementCollection classButton = wbMain.Document.All;
foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton)
{
    if (element.GetAttribute("class") == "media-menu-item")
    {
        while (true)
        {
            element.InvokeMember("click"); 
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954739/invokememberclick-in-webbrowser-control

Comment: No, mine is different, I need to know why mine is not clicking on the class.